# Thinkpad E540 setting VFS5011 Fingerprint by using fingerprint-gui: No Devices Found!

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I'm trying to figure out how to set the fingerprint reader in my Thinkpad E540 as this is the only remaining component not recognised during the OS install.

Apparently the setup is quite easy and fingerpring-gui is working after doing an install from PPA sources.

But when I try to use the GUI, in the fingerprint devices dropdown list only appears:

> No device found!

When I run `lsusb` I can see a fingerprint reader listed:

```
~# lsusb |grep -i finger
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
```

As per some research I can't find a suitable solution.

I've double-checked permissions and it's not related.

I also executed `fingerprint-gui` as root but the problem persists. See the screenshot:

[image]

Anyone with the same issue that could help me up?

Comment: Did you check http://askubuntu.com/questions/717304/how-to-use-hp-355-g2-fingerprint-reader-138a0050-validity-sensors-inc ? It worked for me (though I had a `138a:0050` device); there's a good chance that it might work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the permissions for `/dev/bus/usb/003/004` to `666` mode? try this command:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/bus/usb/003/004
```

Or try running fingerprint-gui with sudo command to grant root permissions. that probably solves the problem.

Let us know if it works or not. I have the same problem with my sensor, but it seems that the driver is missing for me. Usually thinkpad uses the Upek brand for sensors, but for x1 apparently they have decided to go with Validity Sensors Inc.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at list of supported devices on [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui). It doesn't support our device :((