# How to use HP 355 G2 fingerprint reader ([138a:0050] Validity Sensors, Inc.)

Tags: drivers, hp, fingerprint-reader

I just bought a new HP 355 G2 laptop and I'm trying to figure out how to make the built-in fingerprint reader work. I have tried installing Fingerprint GUI, but it tells me there are no devices found. Using the command `lsusb` I get this:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
```

Which would mean that the fingerprint reader is recognized. After searching for hours on google, I found this [patch](https://github.com/payden/libfprint), which was supposedly reverse-engineered for the 138a:0050, according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u09k3xN3AsI). Unfortunately I have not been able to make it work, and apparently the creator of this patch passed away in 2014, so there's no way of contacting him for help.

EDIT: I finally successfully compiled the driver, and while it now registers the device, the sensor lights up and I can register fingers, however when I try to use swipe to obtain root privileges or login, i just keep getting "swipe your finger again" until it times out and I have to input a password. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you share what you did to make it work properly?
Regarding your question, you probably need to add your user to "138a:0050 Validity Sensors" group.

Comment: Running some `sudo` command with a `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` running parallely might also help. (Btw, aside from building and installing the above patch, I also had to manually symlink `/usr/lib/libfprint.so.0` to the newly installed `/usr/local/lib/libfprint.so`, as the system kept on loading the old `libfprint.so` despite the new one installed at `/usr/local/lib` (instead of `/usr/lib`).)

Comment: Can you please tell us how you did it?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://askubuntu.com/q/713476/178596